# golang regex to find urls in a string

Tags: regex, go

I am tring to find all links in a string and then hyperlink them
like this js lib https://github.com/bryanwoods/autolink-js

i tried to use alot of regex but i always got too many errors
http://play.golang.org/p/iQiccXvFiB
i don't know if go has a different regex syntax

so, what regex that works in go that is good to match urls in strings

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use back-ticks](http://play.golang.org/p/jI1gwNkIFP) instead of double-quotes for your string literals. Back-slashes inside double-quotes start escape sequences, which you don't need/want for this use case.

Additionally, how did you expect this to work?

```
"<a href="$0">$0</a>"
```

Comment: i solved it using \\, but the core problem is like you said (using double-quotes), so using back-ticks is what i need, thanks.
what do you mean with (how did you expect this to work?), what's wrong, i give the output that i want

Comment: This `"<a href="$0">$0</a>"` is a string literal `"<a href="`, followed by `$0` (which means nothing in Go), followed by the string `">$0</a>"`. If you're going to use double-quotes, then you can't use double quotes inside of the string, unless you escape them.

Comment: right, i already changed it to '<a href="$0" targe="_blank" rel="nofollow">$0</a>', thanks

Answer (score 10):

You can use [xurls](https://github.com/mvdan/xurls):

```
import "mvdan.cc/xurls"

func main() {
        xurls.Relaxed().FindString("Do gophers live in golang.org?")
        // "golang.org"
        xurls.Relaxed().FindAllString("foo.com is http://foo.com/.", -1)
        // ["foo.com", "http://foo.com/"]
        xurls.Strict().FindAllString("foo.com is http://foo.com/.", -1)
        // ["http://foo.com/"]
}
```